# QTableView Selecion Change

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

Been googling around for some time on this one but I can't seem to find anything.  Need the signal for QTableView on a selection change.  Tried `tbl_view.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.select_row)` but the compiler complains this doesn't exist.  I also need to retrieve the data from the row that is selected.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`itemSelectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) is a `QTableWidget` signal since in that class the concept of item exists, but in QTableView it does not. In the case of `QTableView`, `QListView` and `QTreeView` have the method called [`selectionModel()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) that returns a model that tracks the selected elements, and that model has a signal called [`selectionChanged()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) that is issued whenever there is a change in the selection, for example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.setCentralWidget(table_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 5, self)
        table_view.setModel(model)

        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{i}-{j}")
                model.setItem(i, j, it)

        selection_model = table_view.selectionModel()
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.on_selectionChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot('QItemSelection', 'QItemSelection')
    def on_selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        print("selected: ")
        for ix in selected.indexes():
            print(ix.data())

        print("deselected: ")
        for ix in deselected.indexes():
            print(ix.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, as usual, eyllanesc!

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this example.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Message(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.messageList = []

    def addMessage(self, typeName, data):
        self.messageList.append({"type": typeName,
                                 "data": data})

    def data(self, index, role):

        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        item = self.messageList[index.row()]

        if index.column() == 0:
            return str(item["type"])
        else:
            return str(item["data"])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                if section == 0:
                    return "type"
                else:
                    return "data"

        return None

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.messageList)


class FormMessageJournal(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.messageTable = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.messageTable.clicked.connect(self.onClickedRow)
        self.messageList = Message()
        self.messageList.addMessage("Send1", "Hello1")
        self.messageList.addMessage("Send2", "Hello2")
        self.messageList.addMessage("Send3", "Hello3")
        self.messageList.addMessage("Send4", "Hello4")
        self.messageTable.setModel(self.messageList)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.messageTable)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def onClickedRow(self, index=None):
        print(index.row(), index.column(), self.messageList.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = FormMessageJournal()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```